# debugging osgi classloader issues

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi, taglib

Is there some tool or recipes for debugging osgi classloading issues ? 
Specifically interaction of osgi classloaders with java ee container classloaders and versions. I looked into the spec- a little too complicated for me, prefer some real life examples.

Comment: I am interested in an answer to this question. Therefore I am setting a bounty. I am also interested in good documentation to automate testing of OSGi bundles (what's your favorite OSGi testing framework? why? etc...)

Comment: I have been thinking over this question for a number of days now, but I don't think there is a general pattern you can follow to debug class loader issues, especially in combination with Java EE. OSGi modularity requires 'classloader hygiene', and 'magic' makes that a very complicated business...

Comment: Can you clarify the issues you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Angelo already stated, there is no silver bullet but getting familiar with the domain.
I am also a practical guy, the OSGi Spec is one of the better specs out there and is actually quite readable. What i did when learning the nuts and bolts of OSGi, i wrote a Test Framework for OSGi Bundles and Frameworks.
Its Pax Exam, no shameless plug here ;) Its the way i learned it and i can only give you this hint: Read the spec, and play with Pax Exam. Even if you don't understand every detail of what Exam is doing, its a playful way to dive into OSGi.

Please understand that this is not about debugging. In general, you should prefer writing tests over increasing your debugger skills. It gives you much better understanding and has long term value.
Maybe this helps?
Let me know if i can help with a particular issue.

Toni

Comment: I agree that (automated) testing is better than debugging. On my side, I am anxious about SecureClassLoader and implementing security in OSGi. How can this be tested? How does it integrate with container classloaders? Can Pax Exam help here? If yes, how?

Comment: I will assign you the bounty. I have been doing more reading and I believe the security issues I am trying to test/solve are 'beyond' OSGi only, since OSGi can be started from a 'container' itself. It is a matter of setting a proper security manager and security policy in the application loading OSGi and OSGi modules...

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! Feel free to contact any of the OSGi related Mailinglists like on Apache Felix and/or OPS4J to get further help and assistance.